# Dynamically change attribute of html button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html button where the 'data-item-price' attribute needs to be dynamically set on page load. The button has to be html but I can manipulate it with Javascript.

```
<button class="snipcart-add-item"
  data-item-id="Job123"
  data-item-price= 18 *a dynamically passed number*
  data-item-url= "www.abc.co/priceevaluation"
 data-item-name="Validate">
  Add to cart
</button>
```

Comment: You should add the JS that you can't get to work to your question so we can debug it.

Comment: If you are using Snipcart, you can't manipulate the data-item-price with Javascript. You will receive validation error. Otherwise use json crawler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using DOM's [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) property

  ```
     const snipcart = document.querySelector('.snipcart-add-item')
     mydiv.setAttribute("data-item-price", 18)
  ```
- Using JavaScript's [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property

  ```
     const snipcart = document.querySelector('.snipcart-add-item')
     snipcart.dataset['item-price'] = 18
     //or use camelCase turn into kabeb-case
     snipcart.itemPrice = 18
  ```